# How to update LibreOffice to the latest version?

Tags: libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132837/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-libreoffice)

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've Ubuntu 11.10 with LibreOffice 3.4.4 installed. But, I heard that is a newer version of LibreOffice 3.4.5.

How can I update to this version?

Comment: There will not be a lot of difference between 3.4.4 and 3.4.5. I doubt if you will notice any difference. When you are new, then wanting the newest can take you out of your depth. You already have the latest Libreoffice compatible with Ubuntu and when the next revision is available you will get it through an update.

Answer (score 5):

By installing Ubuntu you will have realised that you do not only get an OS but also preinstalled software like LibreOffice. Most other Open Source software is also available through the Software Center in case it is not installed already.

This has the following advantages for you

- you have free access to Software **tested** to run.
- security updates will instantaneously be provided not only for the OS but also for your software.
- when upgrading to a new release of Ubuntu all your software will also be upgraded.

New software versions need testing for compatibility with Ubuntu. Therefore new program versions will not appear until the next release of Ubuntu. This will be every 6 months. So what you usually do is to **just wait until the next release to see that all of your software will be upgraded as well** without you having to do anything further.

Only very rarely there is a need for an interim software upgrade (e.g. your program gets new features that you can't wait for or has a bug that is not a security issue).

In case you are new to Ubuntu I recommend to **not** upgrade software from other sources than the official repositories in the Software Center until you are familiar with the way we do it here. Even later it is always wise to wait with upgrades until it is clear they have no bugs and will perform nice. If you follow this advice you will be rewarded with a fairly stable system (that however may not always have all brand new features included yet).

[LibreOffice 3.5.x](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libreoffice) will be included in the next release of Ubuntu 12.04 that comes to you in April 2012.

**You are most welcome to install untested or beta software to help finding bugs and thus contribute to make Ubuntu better. This is very easy to do - but it will always be at the cost of stability.**

Comment: 12.04 alpha already includes LibreOffice 3.5.0beta2. By the release time, I am betting it would have 3.5.1.

Comment: @fossfredom: ty for edit - again version not correct - I linked it now ;)

Answer (score 3):

LibreOffice 3.4.5 is planned to be updated on 11.10, see [bug 915223](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/915223). However it might take some time: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates.

A prerelease containing LibreOffice 3.4.5 has been uploaded to https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/915223

Comment: The ppa now has LibreOffice 3.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

in my case LO 3.3.4, which is not in the Ubuntu repos and can be downloaded from LO's site [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/), works much better than the default 3.4.4 that comes with Ubuntu 11.10. LO 3.4.4 and 3.4.5 and 3.5beta crashed more than I could bare. In my opinion, the newer versions do not always mean more stability and compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

type sudo apt-get update
which will install all the available compatible update till now...
It is advised to use compatible softwares..rather than non-compatible versions..look the linux section of following website http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/system-requirements/