# How do I install the latest stable version of LibreOffice?

Tags: updates, libreoffice

LibreOffice is seeing some dramatic improvements each version and subversion that goes out.

I would like to have always the latest version of LibreOffice on my machine(s). I know of the PPA that exists but is it recommended to use it with 12.04 for daily use? What are the pro and cons of using the PPA? Will it break my system/Libreoffice installation?

Does libreoffice get eventually also upgraded in the Ubuntu repositories or does this upgrade happen only with new releases? Who manages the upgrades of libreoffice in Ubuntu and in the PPA?

Comment: For advice regarding Libreoffice 4, see [how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4).

Answer (score 51):

If you want the newest of the new for LibreOffice, you can place the ppa onto your computer:

https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa

Once you click on this link, read the section called "Adding this PPA to your system" to make sure you install it correctly for your 12.04 system.

If this package is to 'cutting edge', I would use the following ppa for LibreOffice that might help as well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To look over the instructions, follow this link here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice
To quote the site on what this ppa is about:

> LibreOffice test builds and backports
>
> Most of the packages in this ppa have only experienced minor testing
>   -- in fact it is the place to enable a wider audience to test packages before they are published into the distro proper. In general this ppa
>   is *not* for the average user to install without a closer look (if it
>   would be, its packages would be in the main repositories).
>
> In general, users are adviced to take a look at the changelog for the
>   details about a package. If there is a specific bug that is intended
>   to be addressed by an update released into the ppa, you are encouraged
>   to test, if the update solves that problem. Packages published after
>   the distro release are mostly such specific fixes. Critical fixes will
>   SRUed into the main repositories after testing anyway (later, with
>   more testing).

See also:

- [Will 12.04 get LibreOffice 3.6 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178052/will-12-04-get-libreoffice-3-6-and-later/178247#178247)
- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: When do LibreOffice updates get eventually pushed in the main Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: If/when they get synced to the development release.  Ubuntu tries not to update the main repositories often, not without stringent testing to make sure things break.  Exceptions are sometimes made, in cases of critical bugs (regressions), or security bugfixes (which end up in `$release-security`, i.e. `precise-security`).

Comment: note that PPA like ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4 only contains stable releases, not test builds... Read here: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-4-4

Answer (score 6):

you can download the  files from libreoffice.org site at http://www.libreoffice.org/download

Warning: If you are installing 3.6 alongside of older version then you may have some conflicts. So its better to remove the older version and try out the new one.

Steps to remove older version
`sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core`

To install 3.6

Download the 32 or 64 bit 3.6 version and extract the **LibO_3.6.0_Linux_x86(-64)_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz** file

**cd** to the extracted directory and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: If you want to install a newer version of LibreOffice than the one in the official Ubuntu repos, it is advised to use the (libreoffice/ppa)[https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa] instead of downloading the files. "it is _way_ _better_ to use packages from this PPA than using the *.deb files that The Document Foundation provides upstream, which are intentionally build against a very old baseline for maximum compatibility. So, _if_ you want to be on the bleeding edge, do it here, not with upstream *.debs" ((PPA website)[https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa])

Answer (score 5):

**October-1-2015**

Open terminal and run the following commands:

**Latest version of LibreOffice 5.0.x** : (14.04,15.04,15.10)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Note: The above PPA provides LibreOffice 5.0.x updates.If LibreOffice 5.1 released then we need to use another PPA.

For any version we can use `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` PPA:

**LibreOffice 5.x**:(12.04,14.04,15.04,15.10)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Method 2**:

Install by downloading `.deb` file from [here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/)

Answer (score 5):

There is no PPA that simply maintains the latest stable version of LibreOffice (meaning: the version that The Document Foundation proposes as the latest stable version).

The options for installing LibreOffice are:

- the official Ubuntu repository (which installs often a version of LibreOffice that is a bit outdated)
- the ["Fresh" PPA](http://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`, which installs a version that is rather cutting edge and has only received minor testing, so not actually recommended for the average user
- the PPA for a specific version, eg. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-3` (note the version number at the end)
- not recommended (see explanation on the [Fresh PPA webpage](http://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)): downloading the files (.deb) from the [LibreOffice download page](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/)

So **to install the latest stable version of LibreOffice**, as far as I can see the safest way would be:

1. check on the [LibreOffice download page](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/) what version they propose as stable (eg. 5.3.7)
2. add the corresponding PPA (eg. libreoffice-5-3, note the version number at the end) to your system. You can find links to these different PPA's on the [Fresh PPA page](http://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Following those links you will also find installation instructions.
3. Periodically check what version is considered stable by the Document Foundation (cfr. point 1 above), and if necessary install the new stable version (cfr. point 2 above).

Answer (score 3):

Just saw, that the LibreOffice Launchpad Team has created separate PPAs for the different versions from 3.4 to 4.0 plus pre-releases for the brave and a general ppa for those who want the latest stable release.

Links to the PPAs: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice

See the other answers for installation instructions

Answer (score 2):

**As of 2017, LibreOffice is also available as a Snap!**

Let's compare versions:

```
$ apt show libreoffice | grep Version       // deb in Ubuntu (not PPA)
Version: 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5

$ snap find libreoffice                     // snap in Ubuntu
Name         Version  Developer  Notes  Summary
libreoffice  6.0.1.1  canonical  -      LibreOffice is a powerful office suite including word processing and creation of spreadsheets, slideshows and databases
```

First, uninstall the deb version to prevent confusion

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice
sudo apt autoremove
```

Second, install the snap version

```
sudo snap install libreoffice
```

Snaps are not debs. Snaps don't use apt. Snaps don't upgrade automatically. Upgrade snaps to the latest version using:

```
sudo snap refresh libreoffice
```

Answer (score 0):

Install / Upgrade to LibreOffice 3.6

To get started, press Ctrl – Alt – T on your keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the commands below to add its PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
```

[image]

Finally, run the commands below to upgrade your system including LibreOffice.

```
Finally, run the commands below to upgrade your system including LibreOffice.
```

**Enjoy!**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-core
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

These four lines in terminal to remove your current LibreOffice, and install the new one. It says it will install LibreOffice 4.0, But I got 3.6.0.1 instead, which happens to be the newest stable version I'm aware of.

Credit to:
http://jaisejames.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/to-install-libreoffice-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the previous version of LibreOffice

   `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core`
2. Download Latest Version from

   https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/
3. Right-click on the downloaded package and choose Open With Archive Manager
4. Extract all files
5. Enter LibreOffice -> DEBS folder
6. Right-click in the folder and choose Open in Terminal
7. Finally, install all .deb packages by running the following command

   `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`