# Will 12.04 get LibreOffice 3.6 and later?

Tags: libreoffice

I see references to PPA's, etc. for latest LibreOffice.
My question is more whether Ubuntu 12.04 LTS will get the latest stable releases of LibreOffice going forward?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There will be minor and stable updates from the same series, that is 3.5.X for precise, but no update on the next major as it introduces a lot of new features. One man's feature are another man's regression (simply because behaviour changed).

So if you want a new major you need to try the PPA:

- [Is there a PPA with the latest version of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16695/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-libreoffice)

See also:

- [State and Overview of LibreOffice Ubuntu Packages](http://sweetshark.livejournal.com/10977.html)

Answer (score 0):

Only security patches are released, for version updates only way is via libreoffice ppa.

Comment: Can you provide information about how to enable and use that PPA?