# When can we get Libre offfice 3.6.0?

Tags: libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132837/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-libreoffice)

When can we get Libre office 3.6.0 in ubuntu 12.04?