# How do I uninstall LibreOffice?

Tags: uninstall, libreoffice

Installing LibreOffice manually on Ubuntu 12.04 works great following the advice in this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/182602/103893

It basically is a matter of downloading the most recent release from the LibreOffice site and running `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core` and `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Doing the above I installed LibreOffice 3.6.3 and it works great.

But what is the best way to uninstall this new version of LibreOffice (for when the next release is coming along)?

Trying `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core` will not do anything, and `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice3.6` does not seem to remove all packages installed with dpkg...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just went through the same procedure as you and I did so by following the LO FAQ post on [uninstalling previous version of community supplied packages](https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/installation/linux/#De-Installation_of_a_Previous_Version_of_Community-Supplied_LibreOffice_for_Linux).

The steps outlined in the FAQ require Synaptic Package Manager. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

From the FAQ:

> Once you have ensured that Synaptic is installed on your system,
>   proceed as follows to de-install an existing installation of
>   LibreOffice:
>
> 1. Launch the Synaptic Package Manager.
> 2. Click in the Search box.
> 3. Enter the string “libreoffice”. You may need to click on the
>      “Search Results” button before you see this filtering string applied.
> 4. This search will display a list of matching packages. In this list,
>      there will be one package named simply “libreoffice3”. Right-click on
>      that package name and, in the context-sensitive menu that opens,
>      choose “Mark for Complete Removal”.
>
> You will be prompted to accept the marking of a number of additional
>   changes. Accept these additional changes.
>
> In the packages list, scroll down until you see the first package that
>   is not yet marked for removal. Right-click on that package name and,
>   in the context-sensitive menu that opens, choose “Mark for Complete
>   Removal”.
>
> Do the same for the next package. You will be prompted to accept the
>   marking of a number of additional changes. Accept these additional
>   changes.
>
> Continue right down to the bottom of the list and mark every single
>   listed package for complete removal.

Comment: Thanks, MHC. I did not think of using Synaptic for that.

Answer (score 7):

I also just installed version 3.6.3 from the libreoffice website. Before installing with I purged the old files & libraries with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
```

edit: you also probably want to do this, too, before installing

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```