# libreoffice-core seems to have corrupted

Tags: libreoffice

I had libreoffice Version 3.X installed along with my Ubuntu version 11.
  After i did the upgrade to 12.04, my libreoffice behavior changed.
  I decided to upgrade tto Libre office 4X.

During the setup since i was getting errors on DEsktop Integration,  i tried removing version 3 of Libreoffice.

This seems to have caused  problem with some of Libreoffice files, which seems to be essential to run different application.

libreoffice-core- Depends libreoffice-common  has unmet dependencies

Now, my Update Manager doesn't work and I having problems installing any new apps.

Is there a solution to fix this problem without having to re-install Ubuntu?
I tried to do repair of libreoffice.. didn't work.

Cheers
Anil Rao

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping up with LibreOffice](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210910/keeping-up-with-libreoffice)