# Updating Libre Office

Tags: software-installation, software-center

According to the LibreOffice website as of Feb 24 2018, there is a LibreOffice version 6.0.2. The Ubuntu Software Center installs 5.1.6.2 (that is 1 and a half years old) on my machine. How do I get a more recent version installed? (I am not very proficient with unpacking .tar.gz files).
When will the software center get newer versions?

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/install-libreoffice-5-3-ppa-snap-in-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: LO 5.1.6 (2 years old) usually means you are using Ubuntu 16.04 (also 2 years old). With a few exceptions, deb software is not updated after the OS release - to get newer deb software, upgrade to a newer release of Ubuntu. Example: Ubuntu 17.10 has LO 5.4.5. Ubuntu 18.04 will have LO 6.0.2. Or try the [LO Snap](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014143/19626), available for you now with LO 6.0.2.