# Is there a ppa or repository where we can update LibreOffice to version 3.6?

Tags: libreoffice

On http://www.libreoffice.org/download/ there is only RPM version - when great majority of Desktop Linux users are using systems based on APT...

ppa:libreoffice/ppa seems to be very outdated with version 3.5

It's frustating to see several fixes on Windows version and Ubuntu versions so outdated...

People generally reply as:

- we don't update due to security/stability reasons, etc [example 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96161/how-to-update-libreoffice-to-the-latest-version) [example 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)
- why don't you compile yourself ?

For those easy answers, I generally reply:

- let me decide which version to use at my own risk. I just want to try a newer version and I trust on LibreOffice devs. I understand that update a core lib is very dangerous but Libreoffice is an user application and it don't just break the whole system.
- Why don't I compile ? Because I am a regular user and don't have time to learn it. I would love to have this time but unfortunately, I don't have.
- Red Hat/Fedora guys have the same concerns but they update their LibreOffices...

Comment: debs are also available on the libreoffice page you linked to. Please check the options carefully. See the part in bold: "LibreOffice Linux - rpm (x86), version 3.6.4, English (US). **Not the version you wanted? Change System, Version or Language**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So , I let you decide which version you want to use and of course its all up to you.

**Use it at you own risk**.

Here is the PPA => [LibreOffice - Pre-Releases](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-prereleases) for Alpha - Beta versions of Libreoffice.

**The description from PPA**

> This ppa contains alpha and beta release (before the 3.X.0 release).
>   Only for the most brave and courageous!

**The installation instructions from PPA**

> to test these do:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-core
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install libreoffice
> ```

**The installation instructions from** [Webupd8.com](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/libreoffice-36-available-for-download.html)

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk3
> ```

Here is another PPA => [LibreOffice Packaging Team](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa)

**The description of PPA**

> LibreOffice test builds and backports
>
> There is a PPA dedicated for the 3.5 series which supports
>   Lucid/10.04, Oneiric/11.10 and Precise/12.04 for a more stable
>   experience!
>   https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-3-5
>
> Most of the packages in this PPA have only experienced minor testing
>   -- in fact it is the place to enable a wider audience to test packages before they are published into the distro proper. In general, this PPA
>   is *not* for the average user to install without a closer look (if it
>   would be, its packages would be in the main repositories).
>
> In general, users are advised to take a look at the changelog for the
>   details about a package. If there is a specific bug that is intended
>   to be addressed by an update released into the PPA, you are encouraged
>   to test, if the update solves that problem. Packages published after
>   the distro release are mostly such specific fixes. Critical fixes will
>   SRUed into the main repositories after testing anyway (later, with
>   more testing).

Installation instructions not included , but I assume are same as above.

Last but not least , the warning from Launchpad (this is general , for most (if not all) PPAs)

> You can update your system with **unsupported packages** from this
>   **untrusted PPA** by adding ppa:libreoffice/ppa to your system's Software
>   Sources

Answer (score 1):

The official Libreoffice launchpad ppa: ppa:libreoffice/ppa contains libreoffice 3.6.

Alternatively, you may [download the .deb file](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?nodetect) from the Libreoffice site. Choose 32 bit or 64 bit according to your architecture.